# Nested Map and Apply

Tags: map

There are some other questions on this topic but I could not get an answer from reading them. What I want to do is use `Apply` on some of the arguments of a function, `h`, and then `Map` on another argument. Here is what I attempted:

```
Map[Apply[{h[#, ##]} &, {a, b}] &, {1, 2}]
(* ===>{{h[a, a, b]}, {h[a, a, b]}} *)
```

The elements I want to `Map` over never get used.
But this is not what I want. I want just

```
{h[1,a,b],h[2,a,b]}
```

I could use Table instead of Map but it's slow (slower than just using `Apply` twice) and I was hoping `Map` would be faster.

I understand that `Apply` is using both `#` and `##` but I'm not sure what syntax is correct to force the first `Slot` to be used by `Map` instead of `Apply`.

EDIT: This is more like what I actually want to do:

```
Map[Apply[{h1[#, ##],h2[#, ##]} &, {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}] &, {1, 2}]
```

So I want output as

```
{{h1[1, a1,b1], h2[1, a1,b1]},{h1[2, a2,b2], h2[2, a2,b2]}}
```

where I `a`'s and `b`'s are the random numbers. So to get this, I think the order of `Apply` and `Map` is important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to separate the slots by using an explicit `Function` for the second argument

```
Map[Function[arg, Apply[{h[arg, ##]} &, {a, b}]], {1, 2}]
```

Regarding your updated question. The approach is the same

```
Map[Function[arg, Apply[{h1[arg, ##], h2[arg, ##]} &, 
  {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}]], {1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply you could use:

```
Thread @ h[{1, 2}, a, b]
```

> ```
> {h[1, a, b], h[2, a, b]}
> ```

If you can demonstrate how that fails in your application I will give other methods.

---

It was suggested that I use `Sequence @@ {a, b}` so as to keep `{a, b}` in the given form.  I did not, because I was not clear as to the expected input format and because I felt that it would obscure the syntax.

Taking a guess as to your desired syntax, you might use:

```
f[head_][{q__}, {r__}] := Thread @ Unevaluated @ head[{q}, r]

f[h][{1, 2}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {h[1, a, b], h[2, a, b]}
> ```

`Unevaluated` is needed for cases such as:

```
f[Print][{1, 2}, {a, b}];
```

> 1ab
>
> 2ab

---

Based on your updated question perhaps you want:

```
Through[{h1, h2} @@ RandomReal[1, 2] ~Prepend~ #] & /@ {1, 2}
```

Or

```
Through[{h1, h2}[#, Sequence @@ RandomReal[1, 2]]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

But if this is *really* representative of your usage there is probably a faster way.

Comment: Maybe use `Sequence @@ {a, b}` to preserve the input in the given form ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'm still not sure what *is* the input.  Is it supposed to be the two expression `{1, 2}` and `{a, b}`?

Answer (score 4):

Version 11.3 introduced [Curry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) which can be used to good effect here:

```
Map[Apply[Curry[{h[##]} &, {3, 1, 2}], {a, b}][#] &, {1, 2}]

(* {{h[1, a, b]}, {h[2, a, b]}} *)

Map[Apply[Curry[{h1[##], h2[##]} &, 3][#], {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}] &, {1, 2}]

(* {{h1[1, 0.373787, 0.928873], h2[1, 0.373787, 0.928873]},
    {h1[2, 0.271899, 0.0866199], h2[2, 0.271899, 0.0866199]}} *)
```