# How to use select and map together

Tags: map, slot

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`. I want to `Select` from `list1` using `list2` as a comparison standard.

For example:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8}; 
list2 = {3, 5}; 
Select[list1, (#) < list2[[1]] &]
```

will give me elements in `list1` that is smaller than the 1st element in `list2`.  I want ot use `Map` to get lists of list, each containing sets of elements smaller than 1st, 2nd ..nth elemet of `list2`. Basically the results I want is the same as running

```
{Select[list1, (#) < list2[[1]] &], Select[list1, (#) < list2[[2]] &]}
```

but I want to use `Map`.Then I could not figure out how to get the slots to "find" its appropriate calling function. I was trying something like `(Select[list1, #1 < #2 &]) /@ list2`, but it was very obvious it won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably [(16190)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16190) answers your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map[Function[a, Select[list1, (#) < a &]], list2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Some random test set:

```
n = 1000;
list1 = RandomInteger[1000, n];
list2 = RandomInteger[1000, n];
```

You can select elements with `Select` and `Fuction`

```
res1 = Function[{x}, Select[list1, # < x &]] /@ list2; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.988713, Null} *)
```

There is similar function `Cases`, which looks better here

```
res2 = Cases[list1, x_ /; x < #] & /@ list2; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.004461, Null} *)
```

Your specific task can be done very fast by sorting lists

```
res3 = With[{s = Sort@list1}, s[[;; #]] & /@ 
       Pick[Accumulate@#, #, 0][[Ordering@Ordering@list2]] &@
     UnitStep[Ordering@Join[list2, list1] - Length@list2 - 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.008168, Null} *)

Sort /@ res1 == Sort /@ res2 == Sort /@ res3
(* True *)
```

Comment: This is an old answer, but I can't tell you how helpful it is.  I could never figure out how to do this without writing a separate function to map over the list.