# Referring to arguments in nested functions

Tags: map, filtering

I am interested in executing the following command but don't know the proper syntax to distinguish between nested arguments, here at the `Select` and `Map` levels. For example,

```
Map[Select[secondList, StringMatchQ[myFunction[#], #] &] &, firstList]
```

where `myFunction` is being applied to the elements in `secondList` and the second `#` is using the element passed to `Select` from `Map` (i.e. members of `firstList`).

Unfortunately, I don't have a solid enough understanding of Mathematica to figure out the correct syntax. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: You can use the full [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) form with named arguments to disambiguate things.

Comment: I thought of that, but was hoping to avoid defining a separate function (which given my poor programming skills would be defined outside of Map[], so if you can do it w/in Map[], I'd love to see it.  I appreciate the keyword 'disambiguation' and am wondering if there are any other ways to do it.  Thanks @SjoerdC.deVries.

Comment: Don't confuse the function `Function` with a function in general. Please read the linked documentation and you'll see that you can use it directly within `Map`.

Comment: @Xavier I disagree that this is a duplicate. The linked question is about precedence and is fixed by a pair of brackets. Here references to the arguments of the outer function need to be within the inner function and no amount of brackets can help with that.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You are right, sorry for overlooking. I will retract my closing vote. I was searching for a duplicate as I am pretty sure this inner / outer slot issue was mentioned and answered somewhere else. Does it ring you any bell? I'll continue searching.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP This is [better](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/nested-map-and-apply).

Comment: @Xavier I agree

Answer (score 2):

The `Map` statement can be rewritten as such:

```
Map[
  Function[{elementOfFirstList},
    Select[secondList,
      Function[{elementOfSecondList},
        StringMatchQ[myFunction[elementOfSecondList], elementOfFirstList]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  firstList]
```