# Catch parameter order and error using functional form

Tags: function-construction, return-value

**Question**: Why does this fail?

```
In:= (Catch[#] &)[Throw[17]]
```

> ```
> Throw::nocatch : Uncaught Throw[17] returned to top level. >>
> Out= Hold[Throw[17]]
> ```

These other functional forms also fail:

1. `Function[{x}, Catch[x]][Throw[17]]`
2. `jCatch[x_] := Catch[x]; jCatch[Throw[17]]`

#### Background

I recently wasted time tracking down an error from `Return[]`'s [nonintuitve behavior](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29353/how-does-return-work)  (It doesn't breaks from `For` loops but *does* from `Do` loops!?).  So I tried to replace the `Return` in a function with `Throw` and `Catch`.  I had been advised that it's never good idea to use these without tags, but I don't like having the tag for `Catch` all the way at the bottom of the function because this makes it harder, when looking at a given `Throw`, to locate the corresponding `Catch`.

```
f[x_]:=Catch[
  ...
  ...
  If[y<z,Throw[a,"tag"];
  ...
  ...
  Throw[b,"tag"];
 ,"tag"];
```

Maybe I'm unreasonable, but I'd rather have the tag at the beginning.  So I tried

```
f[x_]:=(Catch[#,"tag"]&)[
  ...
  ...
  If[y<z,Throw[a,"tag"];
  ...
  ...
  Throw[b,"tag"];
 ];
```

But this fails as explained above.

Is there a way to get the tag at the front of the code rather than end?  Is there another construct I should be using instead?  I hear people bad-mouth nonlocal code jumps, but what's the alternative here, putting the entire rest of the function in the 'else' parameter of the `If` statement?

Comment: `Function[{x}, Catch[x], HoldAll][Throw[17]]` works, tho.

Comment: Thanks much, this answers my main question.  Now I can use `jCatch = Function[{tg,x}, Catch[x,tg], HoldAll];` and define a function as `f[x_]:= jCatch["tag", ... Throw[a, "tag"]];`.  Can you explain what's going on here?  I see that it must be closely related to the fact that `Catch[Evaluate[Throw[17]]]` gives an error, but I don't see why.  What does it mean that the `Throw` is "returned to the top level" when it's obviously surrounded by the `Catch`?

Comment: The `Throw[]` isn't supposed to evaluate unless there's an enclosing `Catch[]`. `Catch[Evaluate[Throw[17]]]` has the `Throw[]` evaluate before being seen by `Catch[]`, leading to your observed behavior. Another one for your notes: `Function[Null, Catch[##], HoldAll][Throw[17]]`.

Comment: How would I define `jCatch` to accept both (a) one argument (the tag) and return a single argument function `Function[{exp},Catch[exp,tag],HoldAll]`, or alternatively (b) two arguments (the tag and the expression) and return `Catch[exp,tag]`.  I need to define it with `Function` rather than `&` or a replacement rule, since I need to use `HoldAll`.  And (it seems) I need to use *named* arguments (`Function[{tag,exp},...]`) because I want to return a function (i.e., I'll have [nested function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84675/referring-to-arguments-in-nested-functions) ).

Comment: Did you try the last snippet in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I did. It fails because I want `jCatch[x]` to treat `x` as a *tag* and return the function `Function[{exp},Catch[exp,x],HoldAll]`.  If I define `jCatch=Function[Null, Catch[##], HoldAll]` and give it a single variable, this variable is treated as the *expression* by `Catch`, because that's what `Catch` does with single variables.  The behavior I'm looking for is similar to `SortBy`, which returns a function if given a single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that behavior of `Return` with one or no arguments can be unintuitive, but usage of `Return` with two arguments, where second argument is head of expression you want to return from, is pretty straightforward.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] :=
    Module[{a = x},
        (*...;*)
        If[a < 5, Return[a, Module]];
        (*...*)
        a + 1000
    ]

f[2]
(* 2 *)
f[x]
(* 1000 + x *)
```

I use above unless construct, from which I want to return, is nested.

---

As to `Throw`/`Catch` problems.

[The Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html) of *Mathematica* is that arguments of functions are evaluated before they are passed to the function. So in `(Catch[#] &)[Throw[17]]` expression `Throw[17]` is evaluated before evaluation of `Catch` starts.

`Catch` itself has [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute thus is a subject of [non‐standard evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html) and in `Catch[Throw[17]]` expression `Throw[17]` is evaluated after evaluation of `Catch` started and caching mechanism was set up.

---

As already [suggested in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116206/catch-parameter-order-and-error-using-functional-form#comment315426_116206) to define you own catching function you must use one of `Hold...` attributes.

```
ClearAll[jCatch]
SetAttributes[jCatch, HoldRest]

jCatch[tag_] := Function[expr, Catch[expr, tag], HoldFirst]
jCatch[tag_, expr_] := Catch[expr, tag]

jCatch[tag]@Throw[17, tag]
(* 17 *)
jCatch[tag, Throw[17, tag]]
(* 17 *)
```

You could also make it a "macro" that will be evaluated, in definition time, to ordinary `Catch`:

```
jCatch /: HoldPattern@SetDelayed[lhs_, jCatch[tag_]@expr_] :=
    SetDelayed[lhs, Catch[expr, tag]]
jCatch /: HoldPattern@SetDelayed[lhs_, jCatch[tag_, expr_]] :=
    SetDelayed[lhs, Catch[expr, tag]]


ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := jCatch[tag]@Throw[x, tag]
?? f
(* Global`f
   f[x_]:=Catch[Throw[x,tag],tag] *)
```

Comment: Very informative, thank you.  Your use of `SetAttributes` solved the problem I was describing in the comments on the original question.  That two-argument usage of `Return` isn't in the documentation; is it discussed anywhere?

Comment: @JessRiedel only official mention of second argument of `Return`, that I know of, is [documentation of `nofunc` message](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Break/nofunc.html). From unofficial sources there's [What can I use as the second argument to Return in my own functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/14303) question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following contrived example.

```
chooser :=
  Catch[#, "me"]&[Unevaluated @
    Module[{u = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}]},
      Switch[u,
        1, Throw[1, "me"],
        2, Throw[2, "me"],
        3, Throw[3, "me"]]]]

SeedRandom[42]; Table[chooser, 5]
```

> `{2, 3, 2, 1, 1}`

Does that give you an idea on how you might write your code in a style more compliant to your wishes?

Comment: Well, it's different around the problem.  (Currently I'm defining `jCatch = Function[{tg}, Function[{ex}, Catch[ex, tg], HoldAll], HoldAll];` and then using `jCatch@Module[{...}...]`.  But ultimately the Mathematica evaluation system is still opaque enough that I can't determine easily what's going to work without experimenting.  Can you recommend a place to read about it?  Also, do most people just use `Return` and/or `Throw`, or is there another best practice I should consider?  Thank you.

Comment: @JessRiedel. I have been programming _Mathematica_ for 19  years and I have found only a few situations where I need to use `Return` or `Catch-Throw` constructs. _Mathematica_'s evaluation system is indeed both exotic and complex. I recommend [Wagner's Book](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22724/3066) to those looking to understand it.